# How to load images received from a server into a SpriteKit game?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I want players to be able to see images just loaded from an API into a SpriteKit game scene. Images changes depending on various aspects of gameplay. How do I load these programmatically?

Comment: You need to be more specific about your problem. What did you try? What is the expected result? Can you show us some code? Please [read how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then edit your question to improve it. Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you able to load `.sks` files locally? Are you able to download them from a remote server? You just can't combine the two?